# Keeping rows of pandas df that contain, in a given column, a substring from a given list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df with a column NAME and a column AGE.
I am given a series of names, and I want to keep only the rows in df where the NAME column has one of the names in the series. In addition, the series may not have the full name in the df, but only part of it (for example just the first name or the last name).

Example:

```
df = NAME           AGE
     John Stewart    26
     Mary Doe        36
     Luke Doe        29
     Danny Smith     16
     Jenny Brown     80

series s (or list) = [Luke, Danny]
```

I want

```
df2 = NAME           AGE
      Luke Doe        29
      Danny Smith     16
```

I am trying something (very cumbersome) like:

```
df["KEEP"] = None
print (len(df.index))
for i in range(len(df.index)) :
    for name in s:
        row = df.iloc[i]
        if name in row["NAME"]:
            df["KEEP"][i] = True
            break
        df["KEEP"][i] = False

return df[myData["KEEP"]==True]
```

I know this is awkward, and, in addition, it does not work (additional problem, super-slow, but I don't know why).
How do I solve this problem?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586316/pandas-find-the-rows-where-a-given-column-contains-certain-substring) answers the case if s has just one element, but I cannot adapt it to my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex approach:

```
names = ['Luke', 'Danny']

df[df.NAME.str.contains("|".join(names))]

#          NAME AGE
#2     Luke Doe  29
#3  Danny Smith  16
```

Here use `"|".join(names)` to create a pattern:

```
"|".join(names)
# 'Luke|Danny'
```

Then use `str.contains` to check if any of the name is a substring.

In case you need to ignore cases, use the `flags` parameter with `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
import re
df[df.NAME.str.contains("|".join(names), flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```